# Get name from one element and call to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Disclaimer:This is a unique situation and very hackish.

I have one set of radios that are visible to users and another set that is hidden. I need to pull the name from the hidden set and assign to the visible set.

Hidden radios:

```
<div class="productAttributeValue">
    <div class="productOptionViewRadio">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" class="validation" name="attribute[139]"
            value="86" checked="checked" />
                    <span class="name">Standard Shipping</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            etc etc...more li's
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

A visible radio:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" class="validation" name="PUT OTHER NAME HERE" value="86" checked="checked" />
        <span class="name">Standard Shipping</span>
            <p class="rl-m"><small>Earliest Date of Delivery:</small>
                <small><span id="delivery-date"></span></small></p>
</label>
```

So, in this case, I would like the name "attribute[139]" to somehow be gotten from the hidden radio and called to the name of the visible radio. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
<script>                    
    $(function() {
       var name = $(".productOptionViewRadio span.name:contains('(Standard)')").attr('name');                    
    });
</script>
```

I'm not too sure about the script being the right way to go about this and also not sure how I would actually get the value from the one element to populate to the other element's name field.

Thank you very much.

Update: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/susan999/XBcaF/

Comment: Is it just the one radio button you need to do this with, or several?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment. The whole group would be preferrable. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('label input[type=radio]').attr('name',
  $('.productOptionViewRadio input[type=radio]').attr('name'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XBcaF/5/

Comment: Hello beautifulcoder, Why I don't know but this isn't working for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Added link to Fiddle...if you have a chance to take a look & let me know where I'm going wrong, would really appreciate the help. Thanks again, Susan

Comment: Updated your fiddle (I added it to my answer). You could simplify the selectors but it gets the point across as is.

Comment: beautifulcoder, Ha! You did it!!! Right on, thank you so much!! This is more awesome than I can tell you!! Thank you, thank you, thank you!!! Really appreciate this!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('input:radio.validation:visible').attr('name',function(){
  return $('input:radio.validation:hidden').attr('name')
})
```

Could improve the selectors if know more about parent classes of visible radios, or what elements are actualy being set as hidden

Comment: The getter form of `attr()` only takes the first element of the set into account -- your solution will fill all the `name` attributes with the same value.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi well I assume they are the same since radio sets work that way( shared name). So specifying `first` would be redundant and OP clearly states `one set`

Comment: True, this will work if there is only one set. But why use the form of `attr()` that takes a function, then? @beautifulcoder's answer does the same thing (with different selectors) using only the basic setter form, which will be faster.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi not sure...but for a one time query, doubt that micro optimization is critical.

Comment: Depends on the number of visible radio buttons, but in the long run your solution is O(n²) instead of O(n), which can backfire at you someday :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  why do you think I specified that selectors could be improved with addiitonal info. Am working with only what is known

Comment: No offense meant, your use of `attr()` only intrigued me, so I thought I would investigate a little.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  yeah...guess I didn't need the function argument...no offense taken. Like being able to support my ideas and don't mind being quized on them...helps fine tuning

Comment: Hello charlietfl, I'm not using the CSS classes visible or hidden here so this isn't working for me. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: these are not classes....they are pseudo selectors. `:hidden` works when either the elemnt itself, or an ancestor is `display:none`  http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/ Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: charlietfl, Thanks for clarifying, grateful for your help. I have updated the post with a link to a fiddle. Let me know what you think. Much appreciated.

Comment: somehow you reversed the `:hidden` and `:visible`...works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/XBcaF/2/  , I added ID to radio so could back check easy

Comment: BTW... for the modal you could have simply cloned the radio set...may have been simpler

Comment: charlietfl, not sure what is up with this but it's not working. It's for a site using a shopping cart provider...maybe something in the backend...? I'm copying & pasting your script exactly but when I put through test orders it's not picking up the name values.

Comment: Also, what do you mean clone the radio set?

Comment: do elements exist when you call the code?  As for clone, I assume you added the modal to page, clone means simply copy existing set, so you can place same thing somewhere else.

Comment: charlietfl, I'm getting "Modal radio name is undefined" on my page...thinking it's a bit of a mess with all the shopping cart code & mine butting heads. Pretty sure the elements exist when I call the code but with that error, possibly I'm incorrect. I did not create the hidden radios, they are being generated by the shopping cart's server.

Comment: you will get undefined...unless you added the same ID I added in the markup. Have a live link? In fact if you can add ID's will make selectors a lot cleaner and more absolute

Comment: I added the id, copied and pasted your code exactly. The page can be temorarily viewed at: http://www.bluebasilgifts.com/basket-number-one/#.Upkj3MRDtF7

Comment: need to wrap code in `ready` handler, or place it after modal markup  `$(function(){ /* code here*/}}` new radios don't exist when code run at location it's at in page

Comment: Wow, I must be a total moron...added the ready handler (sorry I forgot to do that) and also placed the script after the modal code. Now not getting any undefined result or otherwise.

Comment: Funny. I'm starting to really hate basket #1 myself. ;-)

Comment: OK..reason is...it's not visible when you run it either. Both sets are hidden. If run code in console after click `buy this` it works fine....because radios are now visible

Comment: charlietfl-i used beautifulcoder's answer below. sorry, nothing personal but it worked. thanks for sticking with me on this, really really appreciate your time!! Good luck with your trading, cheers to you! ~Susan

Comment: next time, provide more context for the elements... would have been far simpler targeting the modal and looing within it

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var checkboxCount = 0;
$("#visibleCheckboxes").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    $($("#hiddenCheckboxes").find("input[type=checkbox]").get(checkboxCount)).attr('name', $(this).attr('name'));
    checkboxCount++;
});
```

I've prepared a Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/MJNeY/1/

Comment: why checkbox when OP html is clearly `radio`? WHere does ID `visibleCheckboxes` come from?

Comment: Hello Pablo Anaya, I am trying this in a bit different manner since I don't have the ability to add id's to the hidden radios...not working. Would appreciate any more ideas. Thanks, Susan